# Frequent errors when trying to get data from the internet via WIFI using Volley library

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

I'm using Volley library to get data from yahoo finance. But 10-25% of the time it returns an error inside onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) method.

java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "query.yahooapis.com": No address associated with hostname

The Interesting thing is this is only happening when using wifi on 3G it works perfectly. By doing some research i have found that this Exception Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined or device is connected to a valid wifi but router does not receive the internet. But when my app starts giving me these errors one by one I can easily launch another internet based apps (like youtube) and they will work fine. I'm 99% shore that this is not wifi issue because:  1) I have tried 3 different places to connect to wifi (all with different internet providers). 2) 4 different devices with different android versions. 3) many users from different countries reporting this issue. It keeps happening more often. 
My volley code.

```
public class VolleySingleton {

private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private VolleySingleton() {
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContextFromAppInstanse());
}

public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

}

```
private void getData(String request) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
        startRefreshingAnimation();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, request, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                mQuote = QuoteJSONParser.parseFeedOneQuote(response);
                if (mQuote != null) {
                  //do stuff with data
                } else {
                   // load from db
                }
                stopRefreshingAnimation(1200);
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "query.yahooapis.com": No address associated with hostname
                // notify user about the error
                stopRefreshingAnimation(1200);
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: did you get an appropriate solution?